# failure to upgrade Windows 10 from Windows 7

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have tried a number of times (6) to upgrade to Windows 10 and they all failed when I get close to the end and my system is being configured.  My previous windows is reinstalled and I get the message:  0x8007002C 0x4000D The installation failed in the SECOND BOOT with an error during MIGRATE_DATA operation.    I have uninstalled all my virus and malware software and done a clean boot before downloading - unplugged all my usb connections but to no avail.   Any ideas would be greatly appreciated before I give up on the whole idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise downloading the Media creation tool from here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 then create an ISO and then install from that.

Comment: Thanks for that I will give it a try - nothing else works

Comment: Tried that, burnt ISO to Disk and went through the same process, this time disconnected from the net while doing so and got to exactly the same stage again with the same result and the same error code/message. I don't understand the problem as I have a new computer with nothing weird or unusual installed on it.

Comment: Check out the setuperr.log located in C:\$windows.~bt\Sources\Panther. Enable show hidden files and system files. This looks to be similar http://brandonpotter.com/2012/10/29/windows-8-setup-setup-has-failed-to-apply-migration-data/

Answer (score 0):

Look at my solution http://www.howto.probably.me.uk/windows10.html
After trying to upgrade from Windows 7 many many times, and failing and just about to give up, I found that this worked.

Comment: Please see my comment on your [other answer](http://superuser.com/a/1095030/364367).  In general, link only answers are a problem because links break and then the answer has no value.  Include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and reference.  You've got both a registered and an unregistered account, which will create problems for you on your own threads.  See http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts.  BTW, repeatedly posting just links to your own website is likely to be treated as spam.